# How to schedule simultaneously two events using sigaction and itimerval structures  in C++ ? 

Tags: c++, scheduled-tasks, setitimer

I would like to schedule an event in a specific time, more precisely, I want to generate a poisson traffic. So I need to send a packet at specific time intervals that are generated from an exponential distribution. I have done some researches on the Internet and found that the `setitimer` method can schedule an alarm signal after a certain time, but I don't know how to use it in my case.

Thanks for the advice. I followed what you have said. I still have a little query: in my code I need to schedule two independant events at the same time, typically, filling two queues simultaneously. This is what I did right now:

```
void Queue_class::SetPoissonTraficFirstQueue(void)

{  // add one packet to the queue 
   struct sigaction act ; 
   struct itimerval timer ; 
   act.sa_handler = this ; 
   sigempty_set(&act.sa_mask) ; // no signal is added to the sa_mask 
   act.sa_flags = 0 ; 
   sigaction(SIGALARM, &act,0) ; 
   timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0 ; 
   timer.it_value.tv_sec = exponential_variable() ; // generates a random exponential variable
   timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0 ; 
   timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0 ; 
   setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, *timer, NULL) ; 

 }
```

And the same function for the other queue but with a different exponential random variable

In the main, I do what follows:

```
int main()
{
   Queue_class queue ; 
   queue.SetPoissonTraficFirstQueue() ; 
   queue.SetPoissonTraficSecondQueue() ; 
   // do business
}
```

I have two question please:

1- Is it a good solution to call the function internally with the pointer "this" in sa_handler method?

2- In the main function, do the two processes occur simultaneously as I want: I mean are both queues filled at the same time?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: The second problem is really unrelated to your first question, and should have been put in a separate question here on SO instead of editing this question. You could always add a link back to this question to provide some background.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to schedule a timer for 6PM today, you get a `time_t` of that time (using e.g. [`strptime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) or other functions), then you can use [`difftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime) to get the number of seconds between now and then. This value can be used for the "value" of the timer (i.e. `itimerval.it_value.tv_sec`). If the interval is cleared, then this will be a one-off timer.

On the other hand, if you want to create a recurring timer, that is called every X second, then set both the value and interval to X.

In both these vases, use `ITIMER_REAL`, and have a [signal](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) handler catch `SIGALRM`.